# rounded corners not containing image / img / overflow: hidden;

Tags: php, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/4JkkF/1/   ///new version of fiddle///

please check out this jsfiddle.

I'm having trouble keeping my images within the borders of their respective divs with rounded corners.  This was really simple until I was asked to put border-radius on everything... any help would be much appreciated...

[image]

a further explanation of situation...

in a CSM  for each "post"  i fill fields...

one gets called with php as a title, one as a thumbnail, one as a description, AND - one as the image that goes into the slider.  (a list of img's) `<img src="" alt="">'s` etc...

the whole layout is liquid - and so i need the image to stay behind a "frame" like div... just like in a background-image in css... and change size without messing up the rounded corners... I can do it with styling the img but i just thought for some reason - that the div within which the img lives would dictate the outer edge... but - so far i am wrong...

Comment: Are you looking to make a div that has rounded corners, with the image as a background?

Comment: i have to use inline images because the thumbnails are populated by php...   background:url();  works great... and that's why i've never run into this problem... that's usually always what i do.

Comment: You should probably add a php tag to your question. Since the background image is being drawn by php and not CSS, that's an important piece of the puzzle.

Comment: done !  good point.  another example is if you are using a jquery slider and are pulling from a list of img's  --- so it's not always php that is the wrench ---

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Is this even a PHP problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a `border-radius`, then the content gets "wrapped" inside the borders -- so the image inside your `div` gets pushed by the corners, not clipped. You can achieve the desired behavior by using the image as a `background` to the `div` instead.

A little working demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/Fnaty/4/).

I hope that helped in any manner!

Comment: thanks - but i have to use inline images... can't put php data in css...  any other ideas ?

Comment: @sheriffderek What do you mean by *can't put PHP data in CSS*?

Comment: ok.  so - if i have a CMS and there is a field for an image... and then - I want to put that image in the css background property...

Comment: like:  background-image: url(<?php call my image here?>);  that isn't possible as far as i know... and also - in my case study of a jquery slider - that doesn't help anyways... but - yeah - that is what i meant.

Comment: @sheriffderek It is possible if you use inline styles.

Comment: Yes.  you are correct.  I used an inline color value for a client to change some accent colors in their WordPress theme recently.  worked well - and fell back to the original css if the left it blank.  I'll do some tests to see If I can apply that to this study.

Answer (score 0):

> but i don't understand why the img is coming out the div in the first place...

The image itself in the 1st case is bigger than the surrounding div.
But the surrounding div has an overflow:hidden plus width & height.

So the surround div.thumbnail wont scale up ..

My suggestion would be:

```
    <div class="thumbnail" style="height:50%;width:50%;position:static">
    <img src="http://derekthomaswood.com/place/blink3.gif" alt="" style="position:static; display: block;width:100%;height:100%">
</div>
<!-- of course adjusting the classes, not as inline css ;-) 
  resizing works over adjusting the div.thumbnails dimensions
-->
```

HTH
Gekkstah

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bootstrap. I placed the image in a card and applied the border to the card.

```
 .feature{
.card{
    border: 4px solid $white;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

}